# Improve Face Recognition

Tags: opencv, image-processing, javacv

I am trying to a develop face-recognition app in android. I am using JavaCv `FaceRecognizer`. But so far I am getting very poor results. It recognizes image of person which was trained but it also recognizes unknown images. For the known faces it gives me large value as a distance, most of the time from 70-90, sometimes 90+, while unknown images also get 70-90.

So how can I increase the performance of face-recognition?  What techniques are there?  What percentage of success you can get with this normally?

I have never worked with image processing. I will appreciate any guidelines.

Here is the code:

```
 public  class PersonRecognizer {

    public final static int MAXIMG = 100;
    FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer;
    String mPath;
    int count=0;
    labels labelsFile;

     static  final int WIDTH= 70;
     static  final int HEIGHT= 70;
     private static final String TAG = "PersonRecognizer";
     private int mProb=999;


    PersonRecognizer(String path)
    {
      faceRecognizer =  com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createLBPHFaceRecognizer(2,8,8,8,100);
     // path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/facerecog/faces/";
     mPath=path;
     labelsFile= new labels(mPath);


    }

    void changeRecognizer(int nRec)
    {
        switch(nRec) {
        case 0: faceRecognizer = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createLBPHFaceRecognizer(1,8,8,8,100);
                break;
        case 1: faceRecognizer = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createFisherFaceRecognizer();
                break;
        case 2: faceRecognizer = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createEigenFaceRecognizer();
                break;
        }
        train();

    }

    void add(Mat m, String description) 
    {
        Bitmap bmp= Bitmap.createBitmap(m.width(), m.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Utils.matToBitmap(m,bmp);
        bmp= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, WIDTH, HEIGHT, false);

        FileOutputStream f;
        try 
        {
            f = new FileOutputStream(mPath+description+"-"+count+".jpg",true);
            count++;
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, f);
            f.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error",e.getCause()+" "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    public boolean train() {

        File root = new File(mPath);

        FilenameFilter pngFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");

        };
        };

        File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(pngFilter);

        MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);

        int[] labels = new int[imageFiles.length];

        int counter = 0;
        int label;

        IplImage img=null;
        IplImage grayImg;

        int i1=mPath.length();


        for (File image : imageFiles) {
            String p = image.getAbsolutePath();
            img = cvLoadImage(p);

            if (img==null)
                Log.e("Error","Error cVLoadImage");
            Log.i("image",p);

            int i2=p.lastIndexOf("-");
            int i3=p.lastIndexOf(".");
            int icount = 0;
            try
            {
               icount=Integer.parseInt(p.substring(i2+1,i3)); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (count<icount) count++;

            String description=p.substring(i1,i2);

            if (labelsFile.get(description)<0)
                labelsFile.add(description, labelsFile.max()+1);

            label = labelsFile.get(description);

            grayImg = IplImage.create(img.width(), img.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

            cvCvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

            images.put(counter, grayImg);

            labels[counter] = label;

            counter++;
        }
        if (counter>0)
            if (labelsFile.max()>1)
                faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);
        labelsFile.Save();
    return true;
    }

    public boolean canPredict()
    {
        if (labelsFile.max()>1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public String predict(Mat m) {
        if (!canPredict())
            return "";
        int n[] = new int[1];
        double p[] = new double[1];
        //conver Mat to black and white
        /*Mat gray_m = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(m, gray_m, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);*/
        IplImage ipl = MatToIplImage(m, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        faceRecognizer.predict(ipl, n, p);

        if (n[0]!=-1)
        {
         mProb=(int)p[0];
         Log.v(TAG, "Distance = "+mProb+"");
         Log.v(TAG, "N = "+n[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            mProb=-1;
            Log.v(TAG, "Distance = "+mProb);
        }



        if (n[0] != -1)
        {
            return labelsFile.get(n[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            return "Unknown";
        }
    }




      IplImage MatToIplImage(Mat m,int width,int heigth)
      {
          Bitmap bmp;

         try
         {
           bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(m.width(), m.height(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
         }
         catch(OutOfMemoryError er)
         {
             bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(m.width()/2, m.height()/2, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
             er.printStackTrace();

         }

           Utils.matToBitmap(m, bmp);
           return BitmapToIplImage(bmp, width, heigth);

      }

    IplImage BitmapToIplImage(Bitmap bmp, int width, int height) {

        if ((width != -1) || (height != -1)) {
            Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, false);
            bmp = bmp2;
        }

        IplImage image = IplImage.create(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(),
                IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);

        bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(image.getByteBuffer());

        IplImage grayImg = IplImage.create(image.width(), image.height(),
                IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        cvCvtColor(image, grayImg, opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2GRAY);

        return grayImg;
    }



    protected void SaveBmp(Bitmap bmp,String path)
      {
            FileOutputStream file;
            try 
            {
                file = new FileOutputStream(path , true);

            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, file);    
            file.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("",e.getMessage()+e.getCause());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

      }


    public void load() {
        train();

    }

    public int getProb() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mProb;
    }


    }
```

Comment: My guess is that you won't get a good answer here. Face recognition is *hard*, and folks have written their doctorates on this topic. You might be better of searching the various OpenCV mailing lists and discussion fora, than asking here, where the target audience is mainly programmers. As such, this is not really a "programming" question, but a question about how to apply the "magic" of openCV to a particular problem.

Comment: @berak yes i tried out already but didn't got any measurable success.

Comment: You can use alternatives, such as face++ API.

Comment: In mathematical point of view, why don't you increase images for training the model. You said it does well recognize known images so why don't you make most of them known images? Of course, feasibility of this approach will depend upon what model you are using for the detection.

Comment: How many training images have you used?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue .. done a lot of research on this topic..but nothing works ..

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar challenges recently, here are the things which helped me in getting better results:

1. **Crop the faces from images** - this will remove unnecessary pixels at the time of inference
2. **Resize the cropped face images** - this impacts when detecting face landmarks, try different scales on test sets to understand what works best. Also, this impacts the inference time as well, smaller the size, faster the inference.
3. **Improve the brightness of the face images** - I found this really helpful, detecting face landmarks in darker images was not much good, this is mainly due to the model, which was pre-trained with mostly white faces - having understanding on training data will helps when dealing with bias.
4. **Convert to grayscale images** - this I have seen it in many forums and said that, this will helpful in finding the edges efficiently - and processing time is less when compared to colour images (3 channels -RGB) - however, this did not help much.
5. Try to capture (register) as many as images for individual **person in different angles, lightings and other variations** - this one really helps as it is comparing with encodings of the stored images.
6. Try to **implement 1-1 comparison for face verification** - for example, in my system, I have captured 10 pictures for each person, and at the time of verification, I am comparing against 10 pictures, instead of all the encodings of all the persons stored in the system. This will provide, false positives, however use-cases are limited in this setup, I am using it for face authentication, and compare the new face against existing faces where mobile number is same.

My understanding as of today, face recognition system works great and but not 100% accurate, we have to **understand the model architecture, training data and our requirement and deploy it accordingly** to get better outcome. Here are some points which **helped me improve overall system**:

1. **Implement fallback method** - provide option to user, when our system failed to detects them correctly, example, if face authentication failed for some reason, show them enter PIN option
2. In critical system - add periodic **human intervention** to confirm system result - for example, if a system not allows a user based on FR result - verify with a human agent for failed result and allow the user
3. **Implement multiple factors for authentication** - deploy face recognition system as addition to existing system - for example, after user logged in with credentials - verify them its intended person using face recognition system
4. Design your **user interface** in a way, at the time of verification, how user should behave like open eyes, close mouth, etc without impacting user experience
5. Provide **clear instruction to users**, when they are dealing with the system - for example, let user know, FR system integrated and they need to show their faces in good lighting condition, etc.